# Create a protocol to retrieve data from a UINavigationController to a UIViewController

Tags: delegates, protocols, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I have a parent UIViewController from which I present a UITableViewController with an embed in UINavigationController from which I have to select some rows ( in my case rows with people name ), add them to a mutableArray which I must send back to the UIViewController.

I have tried a normal protocol:

```
@class TableViewController
@protocol TableViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)sendFrom:(TableViewController *)controller theList:(NSMutableArray *)list;
@end
... 
@proprety (nonatomic, strong) id<TableViewDelegate> delegate;
...
```

then in the TableViewController.m
...
-(IBAction)dissmisController:(id)sender
{
[self.delegate sendFrom:self theList:_theListOfPersons];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

then the ViewController.h

```
 #import "TableViewController.h"
```

then I add the delegate

```
  <TableViewDelegate>
```

then I implement the method of the protocol

```
-(void)sendFrom:(TableViewController *)controller theList:(NSMutableArray *)list
{
     NSLog(@"the list of persons is %@", list);
}
```

last thing before I run the app is to set the delegate to the segue
[[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];

The problem is that my delegate method never get called.
and also, if I check in the TableViewController.m viewDidLoad, the delegate like

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.delegate);
```

the answer is : (null)

Can anyone explain this?